# .Net MAUI Shell navigating to the previous page is not working

Tags: maui

I have a .Net MAUI app that uses Shell TabBar for navigating. Besides navigating to various pages, some tabs should just execute some code without showing any content. As TabBar does not provide such a functionality, I used OnAppearing() method of a dummy empty page, and after my code call

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
```

to return to the previous page. But for some reason, this does not work, and the empty page is still displayed. If I use some actual page, e.g.

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof("SomePage"));
```

the navigation works as expected, and SomePage is displayed.

Why doesn't ".." work for me?

Here is the code I use:

```
public class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        // Some code I need to execute

        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably because your `Page1` is not on the navigation stack. Members of the visual hierarchy of Shell are not pushed onto the stack, only pages that are not in the visual hierarchy of Shell are, and thus you're trying to navigate back when that's actually not possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#perform-navigation Maybe you can create your own implementation of `Tab` instead by overriding it and executing the code there instead without having to use a `Page` for it.

Comment: @ewerspej Thank you, that makes sense. But isn't there any work around that would allow me to get to the page I was at before going to Page1?

Comment: Never mind, I will just store every current page's name in an App's variable, and navigate there explicitly instead of "..". If you want to make your comment an Answer, I will mark it. Thanks again.

Comment: Each tab has its own stack. Navigation is within the stack. Why do you use interface to run code? Just so you can access it from anywhere?

Comment: @H.A.H. What interface? As I explained in my question, I need to execute code upon clicking on a TabBar's tab. As this is not supported without showing a page associated with the tab, I place the code in OnAppearing() method of an empty page.

Comment: And you are doing this, just so you can have this button on the tab bar all the time?